# Media Keys (Play/Pause Previous, Next) not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, media-keys

I cannot get Media keys to work properly in Windows 10.
I'm using a Dell XPS 15 running Windows 10 Enterprise.

The function keys for mute, volume control and brightness work fine but the play/pause, stop, previous and next keys seem to do nothing at all.
I've even tried plugging in an external keyboard (Logitech G213) and this has exactly the same problem, volume keys work but play/pause etc do not. I have verified that the external Logitech keyboard does work by plugging in to another laptop with working media keys.

Therefore I'm thinking this must be some kind of driver / windows configuration issue but I can't work it out. There doesn't appear to be any specific driver / software for this, all keyboards just show up as "HID Keyboard Device" in device manager.

Googling the issue always seems to turn up things like default media app not set or chrome stealing the media key input but I really don't think this is the issue here. I've got Groove set as the default media app and that is the app I'm trying to control.

Basically i'm looking for any other suggestions?

FYI: I also have exactly the same issue on another laptop (Acer) running Windows 10 Home.

Comment: check your keyboard layout settings.

Comment: Anything in particular I should be looking for with keyboard layout? 
I have it set to UK keyboard layout as that is the layout I have.

Comment: Do you have a program running that can handle those keys like media player.

Comment: Yes I have tried it with both Groove Music and Windows Media player set as the default music player. I have also tried making sure the music app is already open and playing when trying the media keys.